# How to multiply nested dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have repeatedly tried multiplying values in nested dictionaries, as a study material [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932134/multiply-values-in-a-nested-dictionary-by-values-in-another-dictionary), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919860/multiply-a-dictionary-value-by-other-in-a-nested-dictionary) and finally [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-multiply-all-the-items-in-a-dictionary/), but failed too. Here's the last code of my struggle.

```
d1 = {"1 dozen" : [12, "pieces"], "1 gross" : [12, "dozen"]}
a = 1
for i in d1:
   a = a*d1[i]
print(a)
```

I want the result to be: 144 pieces.

Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What you are trying to do is more complex than the other questions you have linked. You are actually trying to construct a graph (even if it only contains 2 nodes), find the root of the graph and traverse it, and at the same time parse strings into numbers and units.

Comment: Unless you are really just trying to multiply the numbers, regardless of what the strings are. Then you are only missing a `[0]` after `d1[i]`.

Comment: thank you , your help really release the headache in my head